# Heroku provided DATABASE_URL is incorrect

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

We're migrating our ORM from Sequelize to Prisma, and we have a Heroku Postgres add-on setup. In Sequelize, we had the connection string hardcoded to the credentials below:

[image]

So our `config.json` looked like:

```json
{
  ...
  "production": {
    "username": "cll***********",
    "password": "548***********",
    "database": "dih***********",
    "host": "***********",
    "dialect": "postgres",
    "logging": false,
    "dialectOptions": {
      "ssl": {
        "require": true,
        "rejectUnauthorized": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now that we're moving to Prisma, we wanted to use the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable provided by Heroku instead. However, the `DATABASE_URL` that's been set by Heroku is:

`postgres://cem***********:e18***********@***********:5432/dbf***********`

The credentials are completely different. Furthermore, if I try to connect to the `DATABASE_URL` provided above using pg-admin, I get the error `password authentication failed for user...`.

And if I try to change the `DATABASE_URL` string like this:

`heroku config:add DATABASE_URL=postgres://cll***********:548***********@***********:5432/dih***********`

I get the error: `Cannot overwrite attachment values DATABASE_URL`.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

A simple `heroku pg:credentials:rotate --app ___` fixed it. `DATABASE_URL` and the other UI are now in sync.